Do we support Azure AD B2C MFA with TOTP using Authenticator app on Azure China/21v?
We confirm that in the default user flow, currently only SMS/Phone MFA is supported on 21v/Azure China. So can we follow similar steps to configure custom policy to enable autheticator app for MFA?
This is the doc we're seeing for how to do it on Global Azure, but the steps may not work with 21v, as the samples codes 'SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMFA' includes facebook as social account provider which is not supported on 21v/Azure China.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#prerequisites
If using custom policy to enable Authenticator app for MFA is possible, then we hope it can be officially supported as there might be technical cases raised by customers.
Any sugguestions or comments would be much appreciated.
Try to use sample codes to enable Authenticator app in MFA but failed due to social account of facebook is not supported on 21v/Azure China.
